# VoiceMeeter Mix Down to stereo missing center and L/R

Tags: audio, htpc, voicemeeter

I'm using [VoiceMeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) to send (the same) audio output from my HTPC out to my 5.1 system, and to a TV in another room (with built-in stereo speakers). I have enabled the Mix Down feature on the Virtual Out for the TV.

**On the TV, I hear no dialog or foreground noise, but the surround tracks are very loud.**

Per [the manual](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf),

> *MIX DOWN*
>
> This button is made to make a stereo mix-down with 5.1 or 7.1
> sound coming from DVD player on virtual input (strip #3). Left and
> right channels, Center, Sub and rear are combined to output on stereo
> speakers

Both the TV and my 5.1 receiver are connected by newish high-spec HDMI cables, to the HTPC video card (nvidia 1060), with the screen in duplicate mode. audio is going over the HDMI using the Nvidia High Definition Audio driver.

Here is the virtual input and output in VoiceMeeter:
[image: virtual input and output in VoiceMeeter]

Here are the **Playback devices**. VoiceMeeter is the default device (the VSX-531 device is the 5.1 receiver, and the LG TV is the TV):
[image: Playback devices]

Here is the **speaker configuration for the VoiceMeeter playback device**. Note that if I set it to Stereo, I lose 5.1 sound at the virtual input, and both devices only receive stereo signal.
[image: speaker configuration for the VoiceMeeter playback device]

Here is the **speaker configuration for the 5.1 receiver**:
[image]

and here is the **speaker configuration for the TV**:
[image: speaker configuration for the TV]

and finally, here is the **VoiceMeeter Recording device**:
[image: VoiceMeeter Recording device]

Does anyone have any tips for getting the center, and front L/R channels to come out clearly via Mix Down or another option?

Comment: Could you check the settings of the output device in windows sound properties?

Comment: @mashuptwice, I've added details about the audio device configuration in the windows sound properties. Thanks!